# window.onscroll from webpage not working on react-native-webview

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm currently using https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview for a website to load within the app. The app is essentially a glorified website so everything in implemented on webapp.

Anyway, I've bunch of stylings changes based on window.onscroll function in webapp.
Obviously they work just fine when loaded from browser, whether it be mobile or desktop.

My problem is the react native web view doesn't respond to any of those functions from window.onscroll.
I tried to do something like injectJavaScript inside  but there are many on scroll functions and that will basically mean i am replicating same thing from web to ReactNative just to inject JS. Even then, some variables are dynamic so injectJavaScript essentioally woudln't work unless that injected JS triggers on scroll function somehow.

How can I solve this issue?

TLDR; window.onscroll function on webview is not being triggered when loaded from webview.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug from google.
Android System WebView was having problem this few time but it was fixed on February 1. That's what I mean.

Kindly go on playstore and search for Android System WebView and update it and try again

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "bug from Google"? I'm using emulator so it shouldn't be a problem. Android Studio I'm using is most recent version.
Also, this bug appears on iOS devices + iOS simulator.